# How to calculate the continuum limit of a discrete system?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

The question is based on the following excerpt from the book "Symmetries and Integrability of Difference Equations"

Link: [Book Excerpt](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=xJVwrIHIzu0C&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=continuum%20limit%20of%20a%20discrete%20painleve%20equation&source=bl&ots=XOYZEfEy_6&sig=z46aX6DPh2KaEqipQrMaP809644&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RtxjVY7pNNbd8AXbzYHoDA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=continuum%20limit%20of%20a%20discrete%20painleve%20equation&f=false)

Consider the discrete equation $$x_{n+1}+x_{n}+x_{n-1}=\frac{\alpha+\beta n}{x_{n}}+b.$$

To find the continuum limit of the above equation we introduce a small parameter $\epsilon$ such that $$\epsilon n=z,\qquad\qquad x_{n}=f(z),\qquad\qquad x_{n\pm 1}=f(z\pm\epsilon)$$ and then take the limit $$\epsilon\rightarrow 0,\qquad\qquad n\rightarrow\infty,\qquad\qquad\epsilon n\;\;\text{fixed}$$ which yields $$3f+\epsilon^{2}f''+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{4})=\frac{\alpha+\beta z/\epsilon}{f}+b.\qquad\qquad (*)$$

I have no idea on how one gets equation $(*)$. Any suggestions and hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that from the extended Mean-Value Theorem we have

$$f(x+\epsilon)=f(x)+f'(x)\epsilon+\frac12 f''(x)\epsilon^2+\frac16 f'''(x)\epsilon^3+O(\epsilon^4) \tag 1$$

$$f(x-\epsilon)=f(x)-f'(x)\epsilon+\frac12 f''(x)\epsilon^2-\frac16 f'''(x)\epsilon^3+O(\epsilon^4) \tag 2$$

whereupon adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields

$$f(x+\epsilon)+f(x-\epsilon)=2f(x)+f''(x)\epsilon^2+O(\epsilon^4) \tag 3$$

Now, adding $f(x)$ to both sides of $(3)$ shows that

$$f(x+\epsilon)+f(x)+f(x-\epsilon)=3f(x)+f''(x)\epsilon^2+O(\epsilon^4) $$

which is the continuum limit of the left-hand side of the difference equation

$$x_{n+1}+x_{n}+x{n-1}=\frac{\alpha+\beta n}{x_n}+b$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Thank you. In the expansions (1) and (2) how do we decide to end them with $\mathcal{O}^{4}$ and say not $\mathcal{O}^{6}$?

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure. We could have added more terms to the expansion, but the result had terms up to order $4$.

Comment: You're welcome!